# How to implement multiple dropdown lists in MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Let's say I want to show multiple Drop Down Boxes each with the same values within them within a View using the @Html.DropDownList.
Is there an easy way to be able to render all of these Drop Down Boxes without having to bind something like the ViewBag to each of the months returned?

For example:

Controller

```
List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

var values = (from v in db.Values select v);

foreach (var value in values)
{
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = value.Name, Value = value.Id });
}

ViewBag.Values = PopulateSelectList("Values");
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownList("Values")
```

But what the goal would be is to have something like

```
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DesignStyle)
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.DropDownList("Values")    @Html.DropDownList("Values")
        @Html.DropDownList("Values")    @Html.DropDownList("Values")
        @Html.DropDownList("Values")    @Html.DropDownList("Values")
        @Html.DropDownList("Values")    @Html.DropDownList("Values")
        @Html.DropDownList("Values")    @Html.DropDownList("Values")
    </div>
</div>
```

My guess is I would need some sort of `@foreach (item in Model)` to populate each of the DropDowns on the View

Here is a sample of my initial thought on how to get something going.

```
List<SelectListItem> results = new List<SelectListItem>();
SelectListItem item = null;

var values = (from v in db.Values select v);

for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
{
     item = new SelectListItem();

     item.Text = "Select a value";
     item.Value = "1";

     results.Add(item);

     foreach (var thread in threads)
     {
         item.Text = thread.Name;
         item.Value = thread.Id;

         results.Add(item);
     }
 }
```

What I don't want to do is duplicate the logic to populate a SelectListItem multiple times and put each of those in a separate ViewBag item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the EditorTemplate functionality in order to solve / render this.

The Model changed from this:

```
public class ValueModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

To this:

```
public class ValueModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<ValueDropDownModel> DropDown { get; set; }
}

public class ValueDropDownModel
{
    [Range(0, 15)]
    public int DropDown { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> AvailableDropDown { get; set; }
}
```

Within the `Views` under the folder for `Value`, there is now a sub folder called `EditorTemplates`. This contains 2 Views. A `ValueModel.cshtml` and a `ValueDropDownModel.cshtml`.

`ValueModel.cshtml` contains:

```
@model SomeSolution.Web.Models.ValueModel

<div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="span6">
        <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
        @for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.DropDown[i])
        }
    </div>

    <div class="span4">
        @for (int i = 5; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.DropDown[i])
        }
    </div>

    <div class="span4">
        @for (int i = 10; i < 15; ++i)
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.DropDown[i])
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

`ValueDropDownModel.cshtml` contains:

```
@model SomeSolution.Web.Models.ValueDropDownModel

<div class="control-group">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DropDown)
    @String.Format("DropDown {0}", Model.DropDown)
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, Model.AvailableDropDown)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Id)
    </div>
</div>
```

The `ValueController` now includes some helper methods to populate the drop downs

```
    private void FillAvailableValues(ValueModel modelValue, Entities db)
    {
        var values = (from v in db.Values
                       orderby v.Name
                       select v);

        foreach (var model in modelValue.Values)
        {
            model.AvailableDropDown = new List<SelectListItem>();
            model.AvailableDropDown.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = "Unassigned",
                Value = "0",
                Selected = (model.Id == 0)
            });

            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                model.AvailableDropDown.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = value.Name,
                    Value = value.Id,
                    Selected = (model.Id.ToString() == colour.Id)
                });
            }
        }
    }

    private void InitDefaultDropDown(ValueModel model)
    {
        model.DropDown = new List<ValueDropDownModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            model.DropDown.Add(new ValueDropDownModel()
            {
                DropDown = i + 1,
                Id = 0
            });
        }
    }
```

The `FillAvailableValues` method is called on the `Create` `ActionResult` as well as the `Edit` `ActionResult` to initialize the Drop Downs. The `InitDefaultDropDown` method is called on the `Create` `ActionResult` to setup the Drop Downs on the page.

Answer (score 4):

You can re-use the select list - just use the proper overlad of [`DropDownList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492738%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) or [`DropDownListFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703462%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). What you should (normally) do is give the dropdowns different names.
For example:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor( m => m.PickedValue1, ViewBag.Values)
 @Html.DropDownListFor( m => m.PickedValue2, ViewBag.Values)
```

Or, if you prefer the non-strongly typed `DropDownList`:

```
 @Html.DropDownList( "PickedValue1", ViewBag.Values)
 @Html.DropDownList( "PickedValue2", ViewBag.Values)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but couldn't get it work as I had hoped. Wouldn't PickedValue1, PickedValue2, PickedValuen ... have to each be populated. Similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178175/multiple-dynamically-populated-drop-down-lists

Comment: How would you go about making this more dynamic. Say, if there wasn't a consistent number of drop downs, each time this page was rendered it could have 1 or 5 drop downs. It would be undesirable to hardcode "PickedValue1" and the like.

Comment: @EbbnFlow Simple - use a loop. You probably want some sort of a container (for example, a `List`) with the dropdowns you want to render, then just loop through the list and add a drop down for each item in the container. The list is a part of your view model.

Comment: Thanks. Should there also be a "SelectedValue" string property in the model that is inside of the list container?

Comment: @EbbnFlow That depends on how you're going to consume the POSTed values. Look up how the model binder works for details. [Here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)'s the explanation for arrays.